# How to remove the strings before the json brackets

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a response like this

```
Stripe\Product JSON: {
    "id": "prod_J8FOKA6L9KTYoT",
    "object": "product",
}
```

So while using
`JSON.parse(response)` I am getting an error as there is text "Stripe\Product JSON: " Before

Please help

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the problem at the source, ie. the server side response, not using JS as a band-aid.

Comment: If a service is returning that and setting the Content-Type as "application/json" or "text/json", it is lying and should be brought to justice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myarray= response.split("JSON:");
JSON.parse(myarray[1])
```